# Not able to use EditorPreviewAsyncAPIPlugin from Swagger-Editor in Angular

Tags: angular, swagger, swagger-editor

angular version: 16
swagger-editor-version: 5.0.0-alpha.76

I am trying to show Async-API using swagger-editor@next in angular.

I have followed `the https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/tree/next` documentation.
But not able to import the plugins.
Gives the error "Cannot find module 'swagger-editor/plugins/editor-preview-asyncapi' or its corresponding type declarations."

Even adding polyfills is not well explained.

Comment: You might get a better/faster answer if you open an issue in the Swagger Editor repo: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-editor/issues